# How to set Dockpanel tab text as empty?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, docking

If i am seeting tabtext property as Null or Empty It takes Text property as tabtext property this is Default behaviour of TabText in Dock panel

```
               Dockpanel dck= new DockPabel()
               dck.TabText ="";
```

if u give like this it will take default text property as TabText property

```
               dck.TabText=" ";
```

if u give like this means i am getting a extra space in tab,

I just need to show the tab image no need to show TabText on collapsed state

But i need to set it tab text as " " or Empty

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the both properties of your `DockPanel` to `String.Empty`

```
dockPanel.Text = String.Empty;
dockPanel.TabText = String.Empty;
```